# Trying to reassign var but it does not change

Tags: javascript, var

new to coding and JS for that matter, early on I learned you can change reassign var but in the case below trying to change skyscraper to London is not working.

```
var city = 'New York City';

const logCitySkyline = () => {
var skyscraper = 'Empire State Building';
return 'The stars over the ' + skyscraper + ' in ' + city; 
skyscraper = "London";
};

console.log(logCitySkyline());
```

Comment: Code after the `return`will never execute.

Comment: If it were to actually work, what are you expecting to happen? When you tell us that, we might actually tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `logCitySkylin` the `return` statement breaks out of the function meaning no more code after it will be executed. There would be no point in changing the value anyways as you're never using the variable again in that function call.

```js
var city = 'New York City';

const logCitySkyline = () => {
var skyscraper = 'Empire State Building';
return 'The stars over the ' + skyscraper + ' in ' + city; 
};

console.log(logCitySkyline());
```

Comment: So you now created a global variable `skyscraper` which has nothing to do with `var skyscraper` inside of `logCitySkyline`. So this answer makes no sense.

Comment: Right. My mistake I thought he was modifying the city variable...

Comment: Did you see my previous comment?

Comment: Note that in browser if you create variable with out `var` keyword.It will assign in window  object

Answer (score 0):

```
var city = 'New York City';

const logCitySkyline = (skyscraper) => {
    return 'The stars over the ' + skyscraper + ' in ' + city; 
};
console.log(logCitySkyline('Empire State Building'));
console.log(logCitySkyline('London'));
```

your function isn't returning because it isn't running any line after the return statement.

What you can do that you can pass the skyscrapper as an argument to a function.

Answer (score -1):

your variable `skyscraper` does not change because you try to do this inside the function `logCitySkyline` after return. At return the function ends, so the last line of your function will not execute.

You can try this

```js
var city = 'New York City';

const logCitySkyline = () => {
var skyscraper = 'Empire State Building';
skyscraper = "London";
return 'The stars over the ' + skyscraper + ' in ' + city; 
};

console.log(logCitySkyline());
```

or/and this

```js
var city = 'New York City';

const logCitySkyline = () => {
var skyscraper = 'Empire State Building';
return 'The stars over the ' + skyscraper + ' in ' + city; 
};

skyscraper = "London";

console.log(logCitySkyline());
```

Comment: I see its not going to execute if it goes after the return statement, thank you.